# Avoid a wallpaper to stretch across 5 screens

Tags: android, wallpaper

I've been facing a problem. How do I set a wallpaper in Android, without stretching it across 5 home screens. To be clear, I have a resource images with resolution 320x480px and when I set it as wallpaper in Android, it gets stretched across 5 screens, but I want it to show up only in 1 screen (or the same image in all screens), got it?

I'm not interested in using a livewallpaper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. May be there are any private libraries for it.

Answer (score 3):

Only way to have an app do that is using a live wallpaper.

There are two types of wallpaper, static and live.  The scrolling of a static background is controlled by the launcher app.  This is why LauncherPro and ADW can control the scrolling.  When the user chooses a live wallpaper, the launcher simply displays whatever the LWP wants to render, so the LWP controls the scrolling, if any.  This is how MultiPicture LWP solves the problem.

So your only options are to implement a custom launcher (which I doubt you want to do for such minor functionality) or implement a live wallpaper.

And BTW, `setWallpaperOffsetSteps` is an internal method called by the launcher on a live wallpaper, so the LWP knows where it's supposed to be drawing.  You can't call it directly, but you can listen to `onOffsetsChanged` within your LWP to facilitate your own scrolling implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Tap and hold your screen when you get popup "add to home screen"

select "wallpapers"

select "home screen wallpaper"

when you've selected a picture from gallery or explorer you get a screen where you can crop your Image to fit home screen.

On the bottom you can select 2 type of crops.

A big crop for setting it accros 5 screens and a small crop to use the same BG on all 5 screens.
see screenshot:

[image: select crop type]

select the latter, crop your picture and save.

Comment: Thanks tdje! Am looking for a way to programatically do this! :( I am developing an app, and i want this app to set the wallpapers in the way i said!

Comment: Oh haha didn't get that out of your question. If you want to do it programmatically use the WallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps (float xStep, float yStep) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html .  Im not sure but set your step to either 1 or 0. Good luck

Comment: I'll try that..i tried 0, din't work. But what does that mean, do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's not native Android functionality. You can, however, get apps that do it. "Launcher Pro" and "ADW EX Launcher" can both disable scrolling but you may need to create a landscape rectangular image with empty borders at the right size.

Alternatively, the app "MultiPicture Live Wallpaper" may do what you need. A reviewer wrote: "*Lets me use a picture sized the same as my phone's screen as the background on all pages of the launcher. Not sure why that isn't part of Android.*"

**EDIT:** have a look at tdtje's post before you try these. If that works, then awesome. I'm not sure which version of Android that became available in, as I'm using 2.1 without that feature.

**FURTHER EDIT:** In the comments below, Martyn gives us a first hand opinion!

Comment: I use ADW EX Launcher and it has the functionality to prevent the wall paper from scrolling.  Incidentally setting the wallpaper to not scroll also makes your home screen REALLY FAST!  It's the best launcher app out there - support the devs and buy it - it's well worth it.  To note - I'm not affiliated with the devs in any way, I've used all the launchers for the last 2 years and this one is by far the best.

Comment: I want to get the functionality programatically..to include it within an app.!

Comment: Ah... Not sure! :D
Will have a search around.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Settings and clicked on home screen. Then went to wallpaper. I selected my picture and cropped using the gallary app. This had a setting on the top to either stretch or not. I'm running Android 4.4.